Saving HTTP requests with Spring Boot Actuator
I followed guides similar to these - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuator-http - to implement saving HTTP requests of some microservices built with Spring Boot to a MongoDB database.
As long as I stayed on Spring Boot versions 2.x, everything was saved correctly in the "httpTrace" table/collection and the JSON of the requests contained all the expected data:

When we migrated to version 3.x (we are using 3.2.0), we had to update the settings regarding HTTP request-response exchange recording as per the official guide: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0.0-RC2-Configuration-Changelog.
The new table httpExchange is generated and the requests are saved but... some data is missing inside. For example, we can no longer view the header attributes and therefore all mongo queries/aggregations made on those parameters, return 0.

I also tried to force the following line into the application.properties:
management.httpexchanges.recording.include=REQUEST_HEADERS,RESPONSE_HEADERS
but it does not work.
It would also be conceptually useless because by default it would already be like this.
I think the problem is right upstream because when debugging, before saving, the httpexchanges object is already missing data:

Has anyone had a similar problem registering the httpexchanges?
Thanks!
